# Error in setting Search and Settings code in MainyActivity.java

Tags: java, android, search, settings

I am new to Android Studio. I was learning to program via developer.android.com . I was adding the action bar, but now i am facing an error.

```
`

@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle presses on the action bar items
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_search:
                    private void  openSearch() {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Search button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                    return true;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    private void  openSettings()  {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

here is my code, after `openSearch()` and `openSettings()` , i am getting error to add a ';'`but when i add it, it again shows expression expected. Please help me as soon as you can. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are creating a method inside of a switch case.

pull the method out and just use it inside, like this:

```
private void  openSearch() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Search button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void  openSettings()  {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: happy to help :) happy coding!